# Unable to install ntopng in a Docker container (rfkill issue)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-16.04

Here is the error I am getting:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/rfkill.postinst: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/rfkill.postinst: udevadm: not found
dpkg: error processing package rfkill (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
```

And:

```
Setting up python3 (3.5.1-3) ...
Setting up lsb-release (9.20160110ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up dh-python (2.20151103ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20160104ubuntu1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
173 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rfkill
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
MAINTAINER Jean-Nicolas Boulay <jn@yaloub.com>

# Source: http://packages.ntop.org/apt/

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && export COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 \
    && export LC_ALL=C \
    && export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" \
    && export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" \
    && export LANGUAGE="en_US:en" \
    && export LANG=C \
    && dpkg --configure -a \
    && apt-get update -qq -y \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y -q \
        apt-utils \
        lsb-release \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        wget \
        rfkill \
    && wget http://apt.ntop.org/16.04/all/apt-ntop.deb \
    && dpkg -i apt-ntop.deb \
    && rm -rf apt-ntop.deb \
    && apt-get clean all \
    && apt-get update -qq -y \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y -q \
        pfring \
        nprobe \
        ntopng \
        ntopng-data \
        n2disk \
        cento \
        pfring-drivers-zc-dkms \
        nbox \
        redis-server \
        libpcap0.8 \
        libmysqlclient20 \
        python \
        python-pip \
    && python -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install setuptools \
    && pip install supervisor \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* \
    && rm -rf /var/tmp/*

COPY redis.conf /etc/redis/redis.conf
COPY conf/supervisord/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

So how do I resolved this issue with rfkill?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be trying to run `udevadm` as part of its postinstall.

From [searching ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=udevadm&mode=exactfilename&suite=yakkety&arch=any) it seems that the `udev` package provides this.

You *should* be able to install rfkill as long as you install `udev` beforehand.

I was able to get this dockerfile to build:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

RUN apt-get update && \
    # Without this line, it did not build properly
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends udev && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        rfkill && \
    apt-get clean
```